# Get first days in a month with year input and first day input

Tags: java, date, java-8

Here is my code so far. I think I am going about it all wrong.
Help would be appreciated:

Input for year is 2013;
input for day is 2 (to signify Tuesday)

```
public class firstMonthDay {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Year:");        
    int year = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter day of the week:");        
    int inputDay = input.nextInt();

    int firstday=0;        
    int daysInMonth=0;        
    int month =0;

    for (int i=1; i<=365; i++){

      switch(daysInMonth){

      case 1: daysInMonth += 31 ;
      case 2: daysInMonth += 28  ;
      case 3: daysInMonth += 31  ;  
      case 4: daysInMonth += 30  ;  
      case 5: daysInMonth += 31  ;  
      case 6: daysInMonth += 30  ;  
      case 7: daysInMonth += 31  ;  
      case 8: daysInMonth += 31  ;  
      case 9: daysInMonth += 30  ;  
      case 10: daysInMonth += 31 ;  
      case 11: daysInMonth += 30 ;  
      case 12: daysInMonth += 31 ;
        break;
      default:


        switch( firstday=daysInMonth-inputDay%7){
        case 1:System.out.print("Monday");break;
        case 2:System.out.print("Tuesday");break;
        case 3:System.out.print("Wednesday");break;
        case 4:System.out.print("Thursday");break;
        case 5:System.out.print("Friday");break;
        case 6:System.out.print("Saturday");break;
        case 7:System.out.print("Sunday");break;
        default:

          while (month<12){ 
            month++;
            switch(month){
            case 1: System.out.println("January");break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Febuary");break;
            case 3: System.out.println("March"); break;
            case 4: System.out.println("April");break;
            case 5: System.out.println("May");break;
            case 6: System.out.println("June");break;
            case 7: System.out.println("july");break;
            case 8: System.out.println("August");break;
            case 9: System.out.println("September");break;
            case 10: System.out.println("October");break;
            case 11: System.out.println("November");break;
            case 12: System.out.println("December");break;
            default:

            }
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("the first day of"+month+"is:"+firstday);
    }
  }      
}
```

the results should be

```
"the first day of january is tuesday"
......
"the first day of december is Sunday"
```

Comment: You have to add `break` statements to your first `switch`, like you did for the other two. Also, you never set `firstday`.

Comment: "*the results should be*" > And what *are* the results currently?

Comment: you can easily do it with the help of `Calendar` class, there are lots of methods to deal with date, you do not require this much code please refer calendar class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar` is your friend.

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Year:");
int year = input.nextInt();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
    cal.set(year, i, 1);
    System.out.printf( "the first day of %s is %s\n",
            cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()),
            cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()) );
}//end for i
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear for me.
You can use the below code and inputting the date  will give you the day.

```
   String input_date="23/03/2015";
   SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   Date dt1=format1.parse(input_date);
   DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
   String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
   System.out.println(finalDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, this

```
"the first day of january is tuesday"
```

will never happen because in

```
System.out.println("the first day of"+month+"is:"+firstday);
```

firstday is declared as an int.

Also, please give a brief explanation on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write this from scratch. Use `java.time.Month` and `java.time.LocalDate` which were added in Java 8.

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class firstMonthDay {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Year:");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    Month month = Month.JANUARY;
    do {
      System.out.println("The first day of " + month + " is " + LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).getDayOfWeek());
      month = month.plus(1);
    }
    while (!month.equals(Month.JANUARY));
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter Year:2015
The first day of JANUARY is THURSDAY
The first day of FEBRUARY is SUNDAY
The first day of MARCH is SUNDAY
The first day of APRIL is WEDNESDAY
The first day of MAY is FRIDAY
The first day of JUNE is MONDAY
The first day of JULY is WEDNESDAY
The first day of AUGUST is SATURDAY
The first day of SEPTEMBER is TUESDAY
The first day of OCTOBER is THURSDAY
The first day of NOVEMBER is SUNDAY
The first day of DECEMBER is TUESDAY
```